# Robot framework maven plugin "Jython-Netty-Client-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultFutureListeners

Tags: java, maven, robotframework

When I am using [Robot framewrok Maven pluign](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/) and call `mvn robotframework:run` then thebuild is success,but this eception occures after:

I got this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "Jython-Netty-Client-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultFutureListeners
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultFutureListeners
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
    at org.python.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My plugin config in pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>acceptance-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testCasesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/robot-tests</testCasesDirectory>
                    <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any idea what I am missing there?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below. Basically adding org.phython:jython dependency to plugin solves the problem.

```
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.python</groupId>
      <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.python</groupId>
      <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</plugin>
```